# Using SQL to output link to a node

Tags: 7, database, path-aliases

Does anyone know - using SQL only - how to output the link to a drupal node?

If I was using PHP I think it would be something like this:

```
print l($node->title, 'node/' . $node->nid);
```

But I'm not using PHP, I need to use SQL only because the report module I'm using requires it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in `url_alias` table, you'll need concatenate it with your domain name.

```
SELECT `alias`  FROM `url_alias` WHERE source = "node/XXX";
```

Note: if you have more than one alias it will return multiple results.

Comment: if I wanted to have it reference a non-specific node (ie. whichever node applies to that line of SQL could I do something like this:
source=CONCAT('http://site/node/', urla.pid). urla.pid was already selected and is an alias for url_alias and the pid is one of the fields in that table.